# Node.js https GET request with custom CA chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

I'm trying to make simple GET request from my university schedule website. This is the URL https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/ and to be exact https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/index.php?typ=G&id=190201&okres=1&xml where i get XML of my schedule. So I tried to make simple request as below

```
const https = require('https');
const request = https.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl', (result) => {
    console.log(result.statusCode);
});
```

and got error:
Error: write EPROTO 80C5F30601000000:error:0A000172:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong signature type:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/t1_lib.c:1565:

Although when I try to make this request on https://www.google.com/ or even main page of my university https://uek.krakow.pl/ I got 200 OK, so there is something wrong with the schedule website. After few hours of digging I've found out that the chain of CA is broken there.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=planzajec.uek.krakow.pl

**Chain issues: Incomplete**

Now I'm trying to pass those CA certs in requests but for some reason it's still not working. (tried both consolidated in one .pem file and passing array of individual .pem files)

```
const https = require('https');
const consolidate_ca = fs.readFileSync('consolidate.pem');
const request = https.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/', { ca:consolidate_ca } , (result) => {
    console.log(result.statusCode);
});
```

Out of curiosity I checked if it works in python.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/', verify='consolidate.pem')
print(r.status_code)
```

And got 200 OK (without verify parameter I was getting similar error as in JS).

Comment: There is a unsafe fix for it, I can write an answer with that fix but its pretty unsafe

Comment: @ArnavMishra you mean rejectUnauthorized parameter, or any other way to just disable TLS/SSL?

Comment: You can disable it with setting a ENV variable
` process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; `

Comment: Please note this is very insecure

Comment: I know it's highly insecure, but for some reason even disabling TLS authorization either with rejectUnathorized parameter of .get() method, or with NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNATHORIZED it still gives this error

Comment: While in python requests.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/', verify=False) disabling TLS works fine, something wrong with js/node but I'm completely out of ideas

Comment: Did you initialize the variable before the request?

Comment: I tried it out and it works just fine with you colledge link

Comment: Yes indeed
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
const https = require('https');
const request = https.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/', (result) => {
 console.log(result.statusCode);
});

Answer (score 0):

As i have pointed out in the comments. This method is very insecure and there are probably better solutions present on the internet. You can set a env variable to disable ssl and tls completely

```js
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"
const https = require('https')
const request = https.get('https://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/index.php?typ=G&id=190201&okres=1&xml ',async (result) => {
    console.log(result.statusCode);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Even if I create new node project and copy paste this code I still get error... Which node.js version do you use?

Comment: v12.22.10 is the one i use(the default repl.it version)

Comment: can you console.log process.env and check the variable for its value?

Comment: ...
  LANG: 'pl_PL.UTF-8',
  COLORTERM: 'truecolor',
  TERM: 'xterm-256color',
  _: '/usr/local/bin/node',
  NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: '0'
}

Comment: That's extremely weird.... can you try the http endpoint? and what version of https/node do you use?

Comment: or try axios to perform the request

Comment: Tried axios already, same result. Http works, but with this page has only redirection to https from http, but it does give 200 status. I'm using the 17.0.1 and I'm about to install 12.22.10 and check it

Comment: Tried 12.22.10 and it works... Tried few other versions and the last version that it works is 16.14.0. They must have changed something in v17

Comment: And using consolidate.pem as CA works as well